# Linux command file for symbolic links

Tags: linux, file, symlink

when I try to check the type of an executable file, I always get this:

```
symbolic link to <another_file>
```

Then I have to dig further and run `file <another_file>.` Sometimes this could take 5 or 6 rounds. I'm wondering whether there is a way to let file to recursively go to the original file and tell me the file type.

Comment: How about renaming question "How to check the type of a file targeted by a symbolic link in Linux?". On another note, this question would probably be best asked here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `-L` to `file` should make it follow symlinks. From the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file):

```
   -L, --dereference
       option causes symlinks to be followed, as the like-named option
       in ls(1) (on systems that support symbolic links).  This is the
       default if the environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT is defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

use "file -L" to follow symbolic links